Calculate $\int_{|z|=1} \frac{\sin(z^2)}{\sin^2(z)} \, dz$
Apparantly there is a trick which makes it very easy to calculate the integral, but I can't seem to find it.
Is it to calculate the residue in 0 and use the residue theorem? If so, I'm struggling to handle the sin in the denominator.

Where are the poles within the unit disk? $\sin z^2/\sin^2 z = (z^2 + \cdots)/(z + \cdots)^2$.

Observe that the only singularity of $f(z) = \frac{\sin(z^2)}{\sin^2(z)}$ (inside the disk) is $z=0$ and is removable, as: $$\lim_{z\to0} \frac{\sin(z^2)}{\sin^2(z)} =\lim_{z\to0} \frac{\frac{\sin(z^2)}{z^2}}{\left(\frac{\sin(z)}{z}\right)^2} = 1.$$
The function $f$ can therefore be completed into a holomorphic function $\hat{f}$ which has no singularities inside the disk.
